# How to "fly through" volumetric cloud

Tags: three.js, webgl, mapbox-gl-js, raymarching

I am trying to create a Three.js experience (projected on a Mapbox map) in which you can move through the volumetric cloud (I used ray-marching but any other algo you think is better works).
But whenever I move the camera through the cloud, the visuals break as I move into the THree.js box that is used (which makes sense).

Is there an option or approach which would make it possible to move through a cloud? I am open to any approach that is not 2d billboards :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well to tell the truth moving through volumetric cloud in `Three.js` is quite challenging due to the limitations of the rendering techniques. However you can create the illusion of moving through cloud while minimizing visual artifacts:

1. `Volumetric shader` - is used to render volumetric objects, such clouds, fogs and smokes.
2. `Volumetric rendering` - instead of using 2D billboards, you can use this technique like ray marching or volume ray casting
3. `Clipping and culling` - can help to prevent visual artifacts that occur when camera moves into the box used for rendering.

Try each of them, I hope you can find the suitable approach